# Using Concatenate to create Workbook Links on SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, concatenation

I'm using Concatenate to create a link/path and then Indirect function in a separate cell to reference the cell with Concatenate. But it fails to create a workbook link.

Any ideas how I can create a function that will create a Workbook Link and get data from that workbook automatically?

Cell B1 = Name of the Workbook

Cell B2 = CONCATENATE("'https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/exact path/[",B1,"]sheet1'!A1"

Cell B3 = INDIRECT(B2)

I want the link to be created based on the value in the cell B1 and the data from that workbook to appear in the cell B3.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the HYPERLINK function:

=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("https://companyname.sharepoint.com/sites/exact path/[",B1,"]sheet1'!A1"),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'",B1,"'!A1")))